# Convert ieee 754 float to hex with c - printf

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

Ideally the following code would take a float in IEEE 754 representation and convert it into hexadecimal

```
void convert() //gets the float input from user and turns it into hexadecimal
{
    float f;
    printf("Enter float: ");
    scanf("%f", &f);
    printf("hex is %x", f);
}
```

I'm not too sure what's going wrong. It's converting the number into a hexadecimal number, but a very wrong one.

```
123.1443 gives 40000000
43.3     gives 60000000
8        gives 0
```

so it's doing something, I'm just not too sure what.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: `float` is promoted to `double` in variadic functions (see James McNellis's answer).  Try `printf("hex is %lx", f);` instead.  For portable code, look at sizeof(double) compared to sizeof(int) and sizeof(long) to determine whether to use `x` or `lx`.

Comment: How do you know it's IEEE 754?

Comment: @tomlogic: For portable code, don't pass a floating-point value to `printf` with a format that requires an integer. The behavior is undefined, even if the sizes happen to match.

(Greetings from 7 years in the future.  Don't ask.)

Answer (score 26):

When you pass a `float` as an argument to a variadic function (like `printf()`), it is promoted to a `double`, which is twice as large as a `float` (at least on most platforms).

One way to get around this would be to cast the `float` to an `unsigned int` when passing it as an argument to `printf()`:

```
printf("hex is %x", *(unsigned int*)&f);
```

This is also more correct, since `printf()` uses the format specifiers to determine how large each argument is.

Technically, this solution violates the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).  You can get around this by copying the bytes of the `float` into an `unsigned int` and then passing that to `printf()`:

```
unsigned int ui;
memcpy(&ui, &f, sizeof (ui));

printf("hex is %x", ui);
```

Both of these solutions are based on the assumption that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`, which is the case on many 32-bit systems, but isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: To avoid violationg the strict aliasing rule, try *(volatile unsigned int *)(volatile float *)(&f);

Comment: Why can't you just  printf("hex is %x\n",(unsigned int)f) ???
assuming f can fit into unsigned int.

Comment: @Nyan:  Because that won't reinterpret the bits as an unsigned value, that will convert the float to an unsigned value (so, 24.12 would become 24, which isn't the desired outcome).

Comment: This auto promotion to double costed me many many hours. So much frustration :(

Answer (score 12):

When supported, use %a to convert floating point to a standard hexadecimal format.  Here is the only [document](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html) I could find that listed the %a option.

Otherwise you must pull the bits of the floating point value into an integer type of known size.  If you know, for example, that both float and int are 32 bits, you can do a quick cast:

```
printf( "%08X" , *(unsigned int*)&aFloat );
```

If you want to be less dependent on size, you can use a union:

```
union {
  float f;
//char c[16]; // make this large enough for any floating point value
  char c[sizeof(float)]; // Edit: changed to this
} u;

u.f = aFloat;
for ( i = 0 ; i < sizeof(float) ; ++i ) printf( "%02X" , u.c[i] & 0x00FF );
```

The order of the loop would depend on the architecture endianness.  This example is big endian.

Either way, the floating point format may not be portable to other architectures.  The %a option is intended to be.

Comment: +1:  I wasn't familiar with the `%a` format specifier.  Now I feel dumb :-)

Comment: +1 for knowing about %a.  Why '`char[16]`' and not '`char[sizeof(float)]`'?

Comment: C99 is another document that mentions it :-)

Answer (score 4):

HEX to Float

I spend quite a long time trying to figure out how to convert a HEX input from a serial connection formatted as IEE754 float into float. Now I got it. Just wanted to share in case it could help somebody else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    uint16_t tab_reg[64]                    //declare input value recieved from serial connection
    union IntFloat {  int32_t i;  float f;  }; //Declare combined datatype for HEX to FLOAT conversion
    union IntFloat val;                     
    int i;
    char buff[50];                          //Declare buffer for string

    i=0;

    //tab_reg[i]=0x508C;                    //to test the code without a data stream,   
    //tab_reg[i+1]=0x4369;                  //you may uncomment these two lines.


    printf("Raw1: %X\n",tab_reg[i]);        //Print raw input values for debug
    printf("Raw2: %X\n",tab_reg[i+1]);      //Print raw input values for debug

    rs = sprintf(buff,"0X%X%X", tab_reg[i+1], tab_reg[i]);   //I need to swap the words, as the response is with the opposite endianness.
    printf("HEX: %s",buff);                 //Show the word-swapped string
    val.i = atof(buff);                     //Convert string to float :-)
    printf("\nFloat: %f\n", val.f);         //show the value in float

}
```

Output:

```
Raw1: 508C
Raw2: 436A
HEX: 0X436A508C
Float: 234.314636
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach always worked pretty fine to me:

```
union converter{
float f_val;
unsigned int u_val;
};

union converter a;
a.f_val = 123.1443f;
printf("my hex value %x \n", a.u_val);
```

Answer (score 2):

Stupidly simple example:

```
unsigned char* floatToHex(float val){
    unsigned char* hexVals = malloc(sizeof(float));
    hexVals[0] = ((unsigned char*)&val)[0];
    hexVals[1] = ((unsigned char*)&val)[1];
    hexVals[2] = ((unsigned char*)&val)[2];
    hexVals[3] = ((unsigned char*)&val)[3];
    return hexVals;
}
```

Pretty obvious solution when I figured it out. No bit masking, memcpy, or other tricks necessary.

In the above example, it was for a specific purpose and I knew floats were 32 bits. A better solution if you're unsure of the system:

```
unsigned char* floatToHex(float val){
    unsigned char* hexVals = malloc(sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++){
        hexVals[i] = ((unsigned char*)&val)[i];
    }
    return hexVals;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:?

```
int main(void){
  float f = 28834.38282;
  char *x = (char *)&f; 
  printf("%f = ", f);

  for(i=0; i<sizeof(float); i++){ 
    printf("%02X ", *x++ & 0x0000FF); 
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/aliemresk/ConvertD2H/blob/master/main.c

Convert Hex to Double
Convert Double to Hex

this codes working IEEE 754 floating format.

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me (convoluted as it seems):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main((int argc, char** argv)
{
    float flt = 1234.56789;
    FILE *fout;
    fout = fopen("outFileName.txt","w");
    fprintf(fout, "%08x\n", *((unsigned long *)&flt);
        /* or */
    printf("%08x\n", *((unsigned long *)&flt);
}
```