# Floating point in hexadecimal form

Tags: numbers

How can I represent a given floating point number in hexadecimal form? For example,

```
60123,124;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<sign>0x1.<mantissa>p±<exponent>`

```
>>> (1.2).hex()
'0x1.3333333333333p+0'
>>> (1125.2).hex()
'0x1.194cccccccccdp+10'
>>> (7e85).hex()
'0x1.204362b6da56fp+285'
>>> (5e-3).hex()
'0x1.47ae147ae147bp-8'
>>> (-8.).hex()
'-0x1.0000000000000p+3'

>>> (60123.124).hex()
'0x1.d5b63f7ced917p+15'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here (AU) we use a decimal point:

```
60123.124
```

Which my calculator converts to hex like so:

```
0xEADB.1FBE76C8B43958106
```

The principle is the same: where in base 10 the first decimal place represents 10ths, in base 16 the first decimal place represents 16ths.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941095/convert-ieee-754-float-to-hex-with-c-printf) related question.

The `%a` `printf` format specifier is described [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html)